# Java: double: how to ALWAYS show two decimal digits

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I use double values in my project and I would like to always show the first two decimal digits, even if them are zeros. I use this function for rounding and if the value I print is 3.47233322 it (correctly) prints 3.47. But when I print, for example, the value 2 it prints 2.0.

```
public static double round(double d) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
    bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

I want to print 2.00!

Is there a way to do this without using Strings?

EDIT: from your answers (which I thank you for) I understand that I wasn't clear in telling what I am searching (and I'm sorry for this): I know how to print two digits after the number using the solutions you proposed... what i want is to store in the double value directly the two digits! So that when I do something like this `System.out.println("" + d)` (where d is my double with value 2) it prints 2.00.

I'm starting to think that there is no way to do this... right? Thank you again anyway for your answers, please let me know if you know a solution!

Comment: I don't think you can change the way java stores double values. You can only modify the way they are formatted when presented.

Comment: Yeah... I think you are right... I'll have to format my values every single time I show them to the user... A LOT of times! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well, you only have to write the formatter method once, I would not worry about that. ; )

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 double d = 1.234567;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
 System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Edited to actually answer the question because I needed the real answer and this came up on google and someone marked it as the answer despite the fact that this wasn't going to work when the decimals were 0.

Comment: I found the code in quote shows `.30` if given number is `0.3`, so I instead used the pattern `#0.00` and that worked fine so far

Comment: For me, this answer actually does not work. Here's what I get: `13310.0   13676.31   26600.2`

Answer (score 19):

Use the `java.text.NumberFormat` for this:

```
NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

System.out.print(nf.format(decimalNumber));
```

Comment: I edited my question to clarify what I am searching. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm afraid the problem persists even with this option. It just wouldn't print two zeros after the decimal point! Still looking for the OCD-friendly solution    `14641.0    15180.7   15735.19`

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do this:

```
double d = yourDoubleValue;  
String formattedData = String.format("%.02f", d);
```

Comment: This is the answer for one who does not want to round the number in any way.

Comment: I want to store value in double itself after round

Answer (score 3):

DecimalFormat is the easiest option to use:

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
        DecimalFormat twoDecimals = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        return Double.valueOf(twoDecimals.format(d));
}
```

Hope this solves your issue...

Comment: I tried your solution right now... it doesn't work. I put 3 and it prints 3.0.

Comment: My bad. I was too quick and didn't read the ALWAYS. Try changing the DecimalFormat to "##.00". This will solve your issue!

Answer (score 1):

```
java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("###,###.##");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); 
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use something like this**:

**If you want to retain 0 also in the answer: 
then use (0.00) in the format String**

```
double d = 2.46327;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

The output: 2.46

```
double d = 0.0001;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

The output: 0.00

**However, if you use  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");**

```
double d = 2.46327;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

The output: 2.46

```
double d = 0.0001;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

The output: 0

Answer (score 1):

I would just use something like:

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", theValueYouWantToPrint);
```

This gives you two decimals.

Comment: This is the simplest solution!