# How can i get this to execute to two decimal places, comes out as long decimal

Tags: java, double

```
int ptstotal, ptsearned, ptssofar;
ptstotal= 1500;
ptsearned= 750;
ptssofar= 950;

System.out.println("The current percentage is "+(int)Math.round(ptsearned*1)/(double)(ptssofar)*100+"%.");

System.out.println("The current percentage is "+Math.round(ptsearned*1)/(double)ptssofar*100+"%.");
```

The output is a long decimal 78.96736805263% and just need 78.97% need some help

Comment: Use the DecimalFormat class. This question has been asked many times before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060285/java-double-how-to-always-show-two-decimal-digits

Answer (score 1):

Try using printf instead

```
double value = (int)Math.round(ptsearned*1)/(double)(ptssofar)*100;
System.out.printf("The current percentage is %.2f %",value);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was successful also!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) or [formatted output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) with [`printf(String, Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) like

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.00");
System.out.println("The current percentage is "
        + df.format(Math.round(ptsearned * 1) / (double) (ptssofar)
                * 100) + "%.");
System.out.printf("The current percentage is %.2f%%.%n",
        Math.round(ptsearned * 1) / (double) ptssofar * 100);
```

Which outputs (the requested)

```
The current percentage is 78.95%.
The current percentage is 78.95%.
```

Comment: I would think a better formatting string would be `#.00`. You would always get two decimal points then.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point multiplying a number by 1, or calling `Math.round` on a quantity that you know is an integer.  Keep it simple.

```
double percentage = (double)ptsearned / ptssofar * 100;
System.out.format("The current percentage is %.2f%%%n", percentage);
```

Here, you need the `(double)` to avoid integer division.  Then, in the format string, `%.2f` means show this value with two decimal places.  The next `%%` is converted to a percentage sign, and the last `%n` to a line separator.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. I am fairly new to Java so that is how I had it when trying to get it to work. Didn't know many ways to get it to work.